# WLG500g internet/WAN to Zyxel ADSL modem unstable - need tips on further investigation

Tags: router, modem

Every morning (and every now and then during the day) when we fire up one of our PCs (or smartphones) and connect to our Asus WLG500g.Deluxe router (wifi or cable) internet will seem unavailable. In Win7 this shows as the PC being on a "Unidentified Network" with a little yellow exclamation mark icon.

The workaround is pretty simple: the router just needs a little nudge. By that I mean I need to reset the WAN connection. Resetting the thing entirely as well as just hitting "Disconnect WAN" followed immediately by "Connect WAN" will solve the problem within a minute.

I understand that this is not nearly enough info to get a clear answer here, but I was hoping to find help to this question: how can I further track down the problem? Any software/hardware tools, tips, etc are welcome!

What I've already tried:

- Replace all UTP cables (no effect)
- Try a different router (Sitecom, solves the problem, though that router has other issues)
- Try without a router, with a PC directly connected to the Zyxel modem (no internet problems)

Additional info:

- The Zyxel P-2602R modem is for the ADSL internet connection, is a DHCP server on one side, and a client on the internet side
- The router gets a WAN-IP from the Zyxel as a client, and is set up to be a DHCP server for the LAN

Any help or tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen similar issues with dirty power.  The router and modem seem normal but will not pass traffic or have some issue.  Rebooting usually fixes the issue.

Adding a UPS to the router and modem provides clean power and the issue is solved.  Not always the case but have seen it a number of times.

Another issue can be heat but usually a partial or full reboot does not help.

Comment: Thx for the response Dave. Will try with UPS or at least one of them protected power cords. Not sure if it will help though: there are several other devices on the same power cord that work fine, and the router log shows no reboots at all...

Comment: Off and on I got annoyed by this issue, but I never found the problem... until this past weekend. While changing power plugs I noticed a high-pitch awful hissing sound coming from the power adapter for this router. So thx Dave! Answer accepted :) (few months after the fact, but still)